# Is it possible for Excel to check conditional formatting on key press?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have defined a conditional formatting for a cell like `equal to 'a'` but it seems Excel checks conditional formatting after I select another cell (and un-focus the cell which has conditional formatting).

Is it possible to make Excel check conditional formatting on key press?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes and No.**

To literally answer your question; *Yes*, if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> which changes the focus as you said.

To answer your question as I believe you meant to ask it; *No*, if you want it to perform functions as you type. Excel basically pauses as you are entering data, because it can not tell when you are done, until you change cells. When you do change cells, it then knows you are done entering data into that cell and applies the conditional formatting or calculates formulas.